# Sublime text autocompletion for latex3/xparse-defined commands

Tags: latex3, xparse, auto-completion, sublime-text

I recently started using sublime text 3 with latextools and latex-cwl. I like the autocomplete functionality for commands so far, except that it does not seem to work (by default) for my own commands that are defined using the functionalities of the xparse package. Specifically, commands defined using `\NewDocumentCommand` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` do not show up at all in the autocompletion list.

I figured out already that I can manually make and add .cwl files to enable autocompletion for those commands. However, since this is a rather cumbersome task, I was wondering whether there is a way to make the autocomplete work automatically for the commands defined in this way as well? Or if this is not the case, whether there are tools to automate the creation of .cwl files for those commands?

Comment: This should better be asked on a Sublime Text forum.

Comment: LaTeXTools does support `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment`, but not yet `\NewDocumentCommand`. Please create an issue at github: https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues

Comment: I followed both your suggestions. I will keep things updated here as well!